Re-learning mathematical economics
I am a Master's in economics. Although I have used a lot of mathematical and statistical concepts until now, I feel I have rushed the process. As a result, I don't have a very deep understanding of the mathematical framework of economics. So I have decided to re-learn it from the beginning in a deeper way. Where should I start? And what can be considered a good progression in this scenario? Also, what are the resources that you guys have followed that have improved your mathematical intuition in economics?
Thanks:)

I think it would help others to answer your question if people know what kind of math background you have reached up until now ? Maybe others do but  I don't know what post-graduate means ?

@markleeds I meant to say Master's.

@What is your intention? Do you want to be a theorist in economics (be able to invent abstract models and play with them around? Or do some econometrics? Or just for fun of it? The usual suggestion is to read Mas-Colell-Whinston-Green from cover to cover.

This seems like the kind of question which should be asked on Reddit.

@garej I just want the understand it well enough. Coming to your suggestion, I tried reading MWG. Found it a bit difficult.  Would it be a good strategy to read MWG and wherever i get stuck, clear the mathematical concepts using supplementary resources and move on to the next roadblock and so on?

@EconJohn Why so? I don't understand? I am new to this. But your comment feels like that one day when I leant about mental accounting in college ;)

@ss91, if you have no focus, it perhaps will be waste of time. I would suggest to take at least one classical math-involved article and try to understand it fully (to all math details). Eventually you will get the grip how do they shape those models. In our day the best assistant is chatgpt and siblings. I'm serious.

@ss91 The textbook by Jehle and Reny might be an easier read than MWG while being very rigorous.

Possible duplicate of: What are good advanced textbooks to learn mathematics for economist? Or have a look at these math-related Qs or textbook related Qs

Also, for MWG and similar grad-level textbooks, there is usually a mathematical appendix that reviews the mathematical prerequisites. Perhaps you can start from those appendices.
